# Proving the Big-Theta and other asymptotic definitions (Big-Theta, Big-Omega, Big-O, little-theta, little-omega)

Tags: limit, proof, big-o

So in a future assignment, I noticed some problems that requested us to just "use" these rules. I was wondering if any rules existed for little-theta, and little-omega as well (using limit as x approaches infinity of f(x)/g(x)).

Also, are there any formal proofs of these rules? I've managed to write proofs for several of them (Big-O, little-theta, little-omega). But I'm having trouble with the others -- namely at the moment, Big-Omega. I'm using a limit ratio, and then translating that using the definition of a formal limit, and then applying the definition of the asymptotic notation in question.

So I saw this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925053/using-limits-to-determine-big-o-big-omega-and-big-theta

http://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/lectures/lectures13/AA01-AofA.pdf

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitions which do not involve limits are provided here:

Big O

> f = O(g) iff there exists n0, c > 0 such that for all n >= n0, f(n) < c*g(n).

Big Omega

> f = Omega(g) iff g = O(f).

Big Theta

> f = Theta(g) iff f = O(g) and f = Omega(g).

Little o

> f = o(g) iff for all c > 0 there exists n0 such that for n >= n0, f(n) < c*g(n)

Little omega

> f = omega(g) iff g = o(f)

There is no "little theta". You might also find "Little o" and "Little omega" defined as "O \ Theta" and "Omega \ Theta"; these definitions can be proved equivalent by showing the sets they describe are equal (i.e., o is a subset of O \ Theta, and O \ Theta is a subset of o).

Answer (score 0):

You can use limits to solve little Omega and little O. There is no little theta.
Here is a video showing how you can solve Big-O, Big Theta, Big Omega, Little O, and Little Omega https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhpfLwe-ERM

[image]